# как лучше создать pdf файл на основе массива данных php

Tags: php, ubuntu, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

Стоит задача создать pdf файл на основе приходящих данных. Данные должны быть отображены в виде таблицы. Стоит вопрос как это сделать с помощью php или возможно серверных программ. Рассматривал варианты конверторов из html, но я хочу чтобы на каждой странице была шапка. Конверторы позволяют делать шапку при явном деление страницы, а мне нужно чтобы это происходило в автоматическом режиме, то есть когда программа сама переносит данные на новую страницы, если они не умещаются и добавляет этой странице шапку. Где было бы отмечено какая это страница по счёту и возможно ещё какие-то данные. Существует ли такая программа? Пытался сделать это с помощью wkhtmltopdf, но он отказывается показываться шапку, показывает, только контент.

Comment: https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf для пыхи поглядите